# MIT Licensed Whitelisting Agents Recommendations

Tags: open-source, security

In reference to this post:
[MIT Licensed Whitelisting Agents](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/245583/mit-licensed-whitelisting-agent?noredirect=1#comment505677_245583)

I am just starting out in cyber security and one of the "tasks" that I was told to do was to install an MIT Licensed Whitelisting Agent. I am a bit confused on this topic because at first I thought it would be a service that I will just be installing or configuring similar to a firewall in windows where services & apps can be allowed/blocked. But when I searched into it all I saw are mostly guidelines on what **"whitelisting"** and **"application whitelisting"** is and on the link above I asked what does "MIT Licensed Whitelisting Agents" meant and I was told it was

> **a whitelisting agent software that's released under an MIT open source**
> **license**

A little bit clearer on the subject I searched for softwares that are under the MIT license but didn't find what I was looking for. I thought after this I would see like a list of softwares that could help me but that was not the case. I'm still a little bit confuse on what it is though I know what it basically does. I just don't have the application to play around with and do tests.

The OS I'm currently working on is a CentOS 7 running on a virtual box and any software suggestion that's compatible to it would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should it run on, what features do you need. Even if the description should be available behind the link, please include those details here verbatim. Links are fine as reference, but the basics must be here.

Comment: @Izzy I updated my question, that is the information I have as of now as I don't have really much to work with yet.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! So what should those agents "white-list"? Software permitted to be installed? Allowed to use certain resources? Just to create a list of apps (not) meeting certain criteria (and what would those criteria be)? "Whitelist" per se is not telling much. And "MIT licensed" in this context simply means the "whitelisting software" should be covered by some MIT license – but nothing about what the app itself shall do.

Comment: ahhh so it depends on the cyber security admin on what type of security policy to do inorder for the server to be secured and prevent hackers from trying to login/access files. i think im starting to get it now, i really thought it would be a specific type of software that i will need to install. thank you for clarifying

Comment: Looks like we're getting closer indeed (don't forget to update you question once you've figured). Your last comment suggests you're looking for a kind of "Policy kit", see e.g. Wikipedia's [Polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) page for an example – where an admin can define rules which app is permitted to perform what actions in which context (and when it needs to ask for authentication of a privileged user, for example).

Comment: Thank you I will check that out. Actually, we are focused on industrial control systems. What kind of whitelisting software would be the best approach for that? What would you recommend?

Comment: As we're still not sure what you want to whitelist (all we have is guesses so far), how should that be answered? I'd recommend to first figure out what you want to accomplish. Then we can look further.

Comment: For starters I want to whitelist ip addresses, unknown applications from running (and installing if thats possible?)

Comment: For the ip addresses, allowing an ip address via firewall, is that the same as whitelisting it?